# printf is not showing before scanf

Tags: c, eclipse, console, printf, scanf

I'm using Eclipse IDE
I have the following simple code in C language:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int a;
    printf("Enter a number");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("You have entered %d",a);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

So as you can see, there are two printf's.
but if i run the code on console My scanf is running before my first printf displays.
And all output printed together after the execution of scanf.

**Then the result will be like this (This is what I'm getting in my console):**

```
6
Enter a numberYou have entered 6
```

**What i really wanted is:**

```
Enter a number
6
You have entered 6
```

I tried adding `fflush(stdout)` but the broblem still exists.
is there any working solution to fix this?

Comment: `fflush(stdout);` between the `printf` and `scanf` lines should work.

Comment: Where did you add the `fflush` call? And have you tried running from a command prompt or shell? Does it work as expected then? With or without the `fflush` call?

Comment: Either `fflush(stdout);` between the `printf()` and `scanf()` calls or end the printed string with a newline: `printf("Enter a number\n");`

Comment: @pmg Unfortunately it seems that many IDE's uses pipes to get the program output into its windows. Then `stdout` is fully buffered and not line buffered, so a carefully placed `fflush` is needed.